# Restart Batch Script

Tags: file, batch-file, restart, auto

I am trying to have a FiveM server auto-restart. Currently, this is how you startup the server

````
echo on
title FiveM
cd %~dp0
:loop
%~dp0run.cmd +exec server.cfg %*
timeout /t 6 >null
taskkill /f /im FiveM >nul
timeout /t 30 >null
goto loop```

pause
````

I want my server to auto restart after, lets say,  1 hour. To stop the script normally you need to cntrl+c.

How do I go about this?

Comment: If that is supposed the a batch file or series of commands, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50710006/edit) and format it using the code option, `{}`, instead of the quote option. Please note that this site helps you fix the code that you've posted, it isn't here to write additional code which bolts onto what you've provided. We expect you to attempt the task yourself, asking for help with issues we can replicate using your specific information.

Comment: What about Windows Task Scheduler?